# How do I get a specific whois on connect on mirc

Tags: irc, mirc

With the new unrealircd 5 series now released, they have introduced a reputation score when you whois a user.

I was wondering if there was a way of seeing this without having to whois as part of a notice.

I am using a snotice code at the moment for an output to a named channel and just wondered if someone can tweak this to include this rep score in there.

```
 on ^*:snotice:*:{
  if (is now a isin $1-) {
    window -nek @StatusNotice
    aline -hp  @StatusNotice 4 $+ $1- at $time on $date
    haltdef
  }
  if (Client connecting isin $1-) {
    window -nek @Connecting
    aline -hp  @Connecting 4 $+ $1- at $time on $date on $network
    msg #mastercontrol 6CONN $4 at $time and their ip is $6
    CTCP $4 Version
    haltdef
  }
}
```

Looking at debug @debug... reputation appears as raw 320 however this is shared with another information line:

```
<- :this.irc.server.international 320 Sleeping_On_The_Job Sleeping_On_The_Job :is using an IP with a reputation score of 3234
<- :this.irc.server.international 320 Sleeping_On_The_Job Sleeping_On_The_Job :is a Services Administrator
```

I just want the "reputation score of 1234" to show on a separate line so we end up with

```
> [12:21] <Titan_Bot> 6CONN rascalDan at 12:21:25 and their ip is [12.34.56.78] with reputation score of 1234
```

I tried adding a basic line of `raw 320:*: { echo -s reputation score is $11 halt }` to the script just to see if it would show anything but it says `320:*: unknown command`

I mustn't have any other part of a whois in this script as it will interfere with other raws already in use.